# Запуск скрипта PHP как задачи cron

Tags: cron, php

Всем привет.

Суть в том, что у меня php скрипт должен выполняться минуты 4. Через браузер все нормально. Когда запускаю его через cron, то он выполняется около минуты и потом прерывается.

Это можно исправить?

Comment: Как запускаете?

Answer (score 5):

Для запуска php как модуля веб-сервера и как отдельной программы действуют различные настройки конфигурации. Через cron Вы запускаете интерпретатор как отдельную программу, ограничение на выполнения сценария по умолчанию - 30 секунд.

Можно изменить настройки для данного конкретного скрипта с помощью функции [`set_time_limit`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-time-limit.php), как написано в ответе [@FLK](/users/6551/flk), но можно и для всех скриптов через файлы настройки.
Если есть доступ к php.ini, возможно, проще поправить настройки глобально, установив значение константы [`max_execution_time`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)

Answer (score 2):

set_time_limit() пробовали?

Answer (score 2):

[@northerner](/users/6536/northerner) правильно подметил про php как модуль к apache и php-cli (консольный интерпретатор)

Запускайте в кроне как:

```
 * 0 * * * GET 'htt://...тот.адресс.который.вы.запускали.через.броузер'
```