# Как php прерывает скрипт после того, как максимальное время вышло?

Tags: php, runtime

Есть код, который очень активно работает до того момента, пока его не прервет runtime error. Вопрос: в то время когда скрипт обрубает соединение - функции завершат хотя бы минимальные процессы? Или все полностью прекратит роботу?

Comment: нет не завершат. все полностью прекратит работу, если вы не предпримите никаких действий к обработке данной ошибки

Comment: У меня есть код который если не остановить АРІ запросом будет выполняться вплоть до того как его завершит лимит времени. Могу потерять данные если обрубает в неудобный момент.

Comment: и в чем вопрос? как избежать? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/827540/Про-работу-php-функции-ignore-user-abort
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/90705/Запуск-скрипта-php-как-задачи-cron/90752#90752

Answer (score 0):

Если выкидывается **exception**, то все приложение останавливается. Смотря как у вас еще обработчик построен.